# how to create drop down button like gmail "move to" button?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, button, drop-down-menu

i have a simple file upload system coded in php.

As part of increasing the UI simplicity, i want to have a similar gmail "Move To" button where I can check multiple checkboxes and then after clicking one of the many possible entries in the drop down generated by the button, some postback takes place.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Ideally, would be to use jQuery. though i am not an expert, i have some small experience using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery [Multiselect](http://lab.arc90.com/2007/11/28/jquery-multiselect/) to do something similar.

Comment: hi that is not what i want. i want to be like the gmail move to button where after selecting one of the entries from the dropdown the postback is triggered

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but there is my button with drop down option list solution using JQuery UI:

Working solution in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGNcZ/)

html:

```
<button id="menuButton">Menu Button</button>
<ul style="z-index: 9999999;position: absolute;" id="menuElement">
    <li><a href="#">Select Green</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Select Red</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Select Gray</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

code:

```
var $menuButton = $("#menuButton");
var $menuElement = $("#menuElement");

$menuButton
    .button({
             icons: { 
                       secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"                 
                    }
            })
    .click(function (event) 
              {
                 $(document).one("click", function () 
                    {
                       $menuElement.css("visibility", "hidden");
                    });

                $menuElement.css("visibility", "visible");
                event.stopPropagation();
             });

$menuElement
    .menu({
             select: function (event, ui) 
                        {
                           $menuElement.css("visibility", "hidden");
                        }
         })
    .css("visibility", "hidden")
    .position({
                 my: "left top",
                 at: "left bottom",
                 of: $buttonElement
              });
```